# jquery - Set select option based on json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

User has selected a country from select list. The option is stored with `var country = $('#select-list option:selected').text();` Now when user opens account edit page I would need the country to be selected by default when the page opens.

Only data I could use is the `var country` which could be in this case ´Great Britain´ and I need jquery to present Great Britain from the select list as selected. How should I do this

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: you need to put this country variable in cookie or something to set it's value on the other page . If you are handling this by C# , then do tell me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can try this using [`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector. Like this:

```
$('#select-list').val( $( '#select-list option:contains("' + country + '")' ).val() );
```

And if `value` attribute in your `<option>` elements equal text content you can do this using only [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$('#select-list').val( country );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use `.filter` to get the option which has same text as country variable value and set its value to select box

```
$('#select-list').val( $( '#select-list option').filter(function(){ return $(this).text()==country;}).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#select-list option["' + country + '"]').prop('selected', true)`